# Can you help me identify this grey part?

Tags: part-identification

Could someone please help me identify this part?

[image]

Comment: I'm quite unsure if this is LEGO part. What is the source of the picture? Is this element from part list for some clone-branded model or MOC?

Comment: The source of the picture are from the instructions of lego clone brand named Blue Brixx. All the other lego parts in this set look identical to bricks in lego instructions. The part has one stud on top and one stud on the side and a bar on the bottom. Is there a lego part similar to this?

Answer (score 4):

Minifigure, Hand Armor - Partnumber 28803 or [15407](https://rebrickable.com/parts/15407/equipment-hand-armor/) Pearl Dark Gray

[image: Part render]